# how do I get Flask blueprints to work with multiple domains?

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualhost

I have a Flask app and want it to work for www.domain-a.net and www.domain-b.net behind Apache + WSGI. I can get it to work for one or the other, but can't find a way to get it to work for both. It seems that the domain which registers first is the only one that works.

Preferably this would work by having two Apache VirtualHosts set up to use the same WSGI config. I can get that part to work. But Flask just returns 404 for everything sent from the second VirtualHost.

Comment: I have a feeling this issue has nothing to do with Flask as long as the server is running properly.  What I believe is the sticking point to your problem is the way your web server is configured.  As far as I am aware, flask does not care what your domains are.  You could have hundreds of domains pointing to the application, you just need to configure the web server properly.  What do the web server logs say?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that having SERVER_NAME set in the os environment was causing this problem in conjunction with subdomains in blueprint registration. I removed SERVER_NAME from /etc/apache2/envvars and the subdomain logic and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set up just one Apache virtualhost.  Then within that virualhost, define your two hostnames using a `ServerName` and a `ServerAlias` directive.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain-a.net
    ServerAlias www.domain-b.net 
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Flask routes should be configured to look at just the request path, not the hostname.

Comment: Tried it, but that doesn't work either. Same result: the ServerName version works, but every request to the ServerAlias name is a 404.

Comment: Do you have "www.domain-a.net" anywhere in your Flask config?

Comment: I'm more looking for an explanation of how to do this than to debug the config I have. I've taken out all the references to www.domain-a.net in the config and code. My best guess is Flask picks up SERVER_NAME from the environment when registering the blueprint. Then requests which don't match that name return 404.